# How to map WiFiPhyKind to Radio type in C#

Tags: c#

In my application, I am using Windows.Devices.WiFi namespace to get the wifi network information. Here, I am using WiFiPhyKind property to get the 'radio type'. But in the UI, I have to display the Radio Type in the standard format (802.11a, 802.11ac, 802.11n ....).
Is there a way to convert it?
Sample code:

```
string radioType = "Unknown";
switch (wifiNetwork.PhyKind)
{
    case WiFiPhyKind.Ofdm:
        radioType = "?????";
        break;

    case WiFiPhyKind.Erp:
        radioType = "?????";
        break;

    case WiFiPhyKind.HT:
        radioType = "?????";
        break;

    case WiFiPhyKind.Vht:
        radioType = "?????";
        break;

    case WiFiPhyKind.Unknown:
        radioType = "?????";
        break;

    default:
        radioType = "Unknown";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiphykind?view=winrt-19041) for the enum seems to have some of the info
Dmg = 802.11ad
Erp = 802.11g
HE = 802.11ax
HT = 802.11n
Vht = 802.11ac

The 802.11 specifications could probably fill in the gaps